# Numbers that could only grow

Tags: lateral-thinking

If, at the time of writing (14th Sep 17):

- **lateral thinking** = 7 940 000
- **puzzling question** = 943 000

then how much is **stack exchange** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think these are

> numbers of hits reported when you put those phrases into Google,

although

> for me the numbers come out just a little different. (And I get slightly different numbers depending on whether I use a browser on which Google knows who I am, or a different one in incognito mode.)

So

> for me, at the moment, `stack exchange` maps to 60 500 000 (as me) or 60 800 000 (incognito).

Comment: and I see something slightly different too... So technically they can not only grow :-S